# How "self" gets to access the key of a local table?

Tags: lua

I am new to Lua, I am studying [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4eNl1rA1Ns). At 38:56, a code is presented as below:

```
Sequence = {}
function Sequence:new()
  local new_seq = {last_num = 0}
  self.__index = self
  return setmetatable(new_seq, self)
  end

function Sequence:next()
  print(self.last_num)
  end
```

My understanding is that `self` is equivalent to `Sequence`, and `self` is set as a metatable of `new_seq`, and this metatable's `__index` is also `self`.

And `last_num` is one key of table `new_seq` but not one key of `self`, how come in the definition of `next` function you can write `self.last_num` as treating `last_num` is one key of `self`?

Moreover, before calling `setmetatable`, there is `self.__index = self`, I thought only metatable has `__index` as a special key, but before calling 
`setmetatable`, `Sequence` is just a regular table and it is not a metatable yet, how come it has `__index`?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, Lua OOP is not very easy for beginners.  It is a legal trick: a table may be a class table and a class metatable simultaneously.  So, `new_seq`(an instance) -> `Sequence` (a metatable for class) -> `Sequence` (a class).  Inside `Sequence:next` variable `self` is an object to which `next` was applied, this object may be any descendant of `Sequence`, this is the essence of polymorphism in OOP.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, thanks for replying. I know OOP in C++ very well. I am not sure what you mean by `class table`, I think in Lua there is no concept of `class`, there is only `table`. And I am not sure what you mean by "`new_seq`(an instance) -> `Sequence` (a metatable for class) -> `Sequence` (a class)."   Regarding your last part, suppose i have `seq0 = Sequence:new(); seq0:next()`, in this case `self` is `seq0`, how come `seq0` has a key of `last_num`?

Comment: Class table contains methods common to all instances of the class.  `next` is in class table too. `seq0:next()`=`seq0.next(seq0)`=`Sequence.next(seq0)`, so self=seq0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short version:

> My understanding is that `self` is equivalent to `Sequence`…

`self` is an implicit argument resulting from the method-style function definition.  Within the function, it will refer to whatever value gets passed in as the first argument to that function.

(The rest of your questions around self arise from that same confusion.)

> I thought only metatable has `__index` as a special key…

A metatable is just a table. `__index` is just a key like any other, you can define a field with that name on any table.  Only when a lookup on a table fails and Lua notices that this table has an attached metatable, the metatable's field named `__index` has a special meaning – because that's where Lua will look for a handler.

`__index` containing a table is just another special case of a handler (because it's so common), `__index = some_other_table` is roughly equivalent to `__index = function( table, key )  return some_other_table[key]  end` – i.e. "go look over there in `some_other_table` if `table[key]` was empty".  (It may help to use the long version and `print` something from there if you have trouble following what happens.)

---

Long version, de-sugaring the code and walking through the details:

A definition `function foo:bar( ... )` is the same as `function foo.bar( self, ... )` (the name `self` is automatically chosen, roughly like `this` in other languages).  Additionally, `function foo.bar( ... )` is the same as `foo.bar = function( ... )`.  Which means the above code is the same as…

```
Sequence = {}
Sequence.new = function( self )
  local new_seq = { last_num = 0 }
  self.__index = self
  return setmetatable( new_seq, self )
end

Sequence.next = function( self )
  print( self.last_num )
end
```

…which is equivalent to…

```
Sequence = {
  new = function( self )
    local new_seq = { last_num = 0 }
    self.__index = self
    return setmetatable( new_seq, self )
  end,
  next = function( self )
    print( self.last_num )
  end,
}
```

So, in essence, what this defines is a table that contains two functions, each taking a single parameter. The second of the two functions, `next`, is pretty simple: it just prints the content of the field `last_num` of whatever table it's passed (using the name `self` to refer to it).

Now, just as for definitions, there's some `:`-syntax sugar for calls.  A call `foo:bar( ... )` translates to `foo.bar( foo, ... )`, so when you have `some_sequence` and say `some_sequence:next( )`, what happens is a call `some_sequence.next( some_sequence )` – the `:`-syntax for definitions introduces an extra hidden parameter and the `:`-syntax for calls fills in that extra parameter.  In this way, the function that you're treating as a method has access to the table that you're treating as an object and everything works out nicely.

The `new` function is a bit more involved -- I'll rewrite it into yet another equivalent form to make it easier to read:

```
function Sequence.new( self )
  self.__index = self
  return setmetatable( { last_num = 0 }, self )
end
```

So for whatever table gets passed in, it assigns that table to the field `__index` of that same table and returns a new table with that old table set as the metatable.  (Yes, this thing is confusing… don't worry, just keep reading.)  To see why and how this works, here's an example:

If you say `some_sequence = Sequence:new( )`, you'll have the following structure:

```
some_sequence = { last_num = 0 } -- metatable:-> Sequence
Sequence = { new = (func...), next = (func...), __index = Sequence }
```

Now, when you say `some_sequence:next( )`, this translates to the call `some_sequence.next( some_sequence )`.  But `some_sequence` doesn't have a field `next`!  Because `some_sequence` has a metatable, Lua goes and looks at that – in this case, the metatable is `Sequence`.  As a lookup (or "index") operation "failed" (it would have returned `nil`), Lua looks for a handler in the metatable's field `__index`, finds a table (`Sequence` again) and re-tries the lookup on that one instead (finding the `next` function we defined).

Which means in this case we could have equivalently written `Sequence.next( some_sequence )` (but in general you don't want to – or can't – manually resolve these references).  As described above, `next` just prints the value of the field `last_num` of the table it received -- in this case it got `some_sequence`.  Again, everything works out nicely.

---

Some more remarks (and yet another example):

For an introductory example, the code is much more mind-bending and brittle than necessary.  Here's yet another version (that's not identical and actually behaves differently, but should be easier to understand):

```
Sequence = { }
Sequence.__index = Sequence
function Sequence.new( )
    return setmetatable( { last_num = 0 }, Sequence )
end
function Sequence:next( )
    print( self.last_num )
end
```

Both the version that you have and this version will print `0` when you run the following:

```
some_sequence = Sequence:new( )
some_sequence:next( )
```

(I've described above what happens under the hood when you do this for your code, compare and try to figure out what happens with my version before reading on.)

This will also print `0` for both versions:

```
sequences = { [0] = Sequence }
for i = 1, 10 do
    local current = sequences[#sequences]
    sequences[#sequences+1] = current:new( )
end
local last = sequences[#sequences]
last:next( )
```

What happens under the hood differs significantly for both versions.  This is what `sequences` will look like for your code:

```
sequences[0] = Sequence -- with __index = Sequence
sequences[1] = { last_num = 0, __index = sequences[1] } -- metatable:->Sequence
sequences[2] = { last_num = 0, __index = sequences[2] } -- metatable:->sequences[1]
sequences[3] = { last_num = 0, __index = sequences[3] } -- metatable:->sequences[2]
...
```

and this is what it will look like with my version:

```
sequences[0] = Sequence -- __index = Sequence, as set at the start
sequences[1] = { last_num = 0 } -- metatable:->Sequence
sequences[2] = { last_num = 0 } -- metatable:->Sequence
sequences[3] = { last_num = 0 } -- metatable:->Sequence
...
```

(If you'd instead say `sequences[#sequences+1] = Sequence:new( )` in the loop above, your code would also produce this.)

With my version, the call `last:next( )` fails to find `next`, looks at the metatable (`Sequence`), finds an `__index` field (again, `Sequence`) and finds `next`, then proceeds to call it as described above.

With your version, the call `last:next( )` fails to find `next`, looks at the metatable (`sequences[9]`), finds an `__index` field (`sequences[9]`), fails to find `next` and therefore looks at the metatable (of `sequences[9]`, which is `sequences[8]`), finds an `__index` field (`sequences[8]`), fails to find `next` and therefore looks at the metatable ... (until we reach `sequences[1]`) ... fails to find `next`, looks at the metatable (`Sequence`), finds an `__index` field (`Sequence`) and finally finds `next`, then proceeds with the call.  (This is why I said it's quite hard to follow...)

The code that you have implements prototype-based OOP, with all the pros and cons.  As you've seen, the lookup traverses the whole chain, which means that you could define a function `sequences[5].next` to do something else and subsequently `sequences[5]` through `sequences[10]` would find that other function.  This can be really useful – no need for all the boilerplate to define a new class to change some functionality, just adjust one object and use it like a class.  (This can also be annoying if you accidentally do this.)

My version implements something a bit closer to the class-based OOP seen in many other languages.  (You can't accidentally override methods for more than one object at once.)  What both of these (and many other approaches to OOP in Lua) have in common is that defining a field of an object with the same name as a method will hide that method and make it inaccessible.  (If you define `some_sequence.next`, saying `some_sequence:next( )` or `some_sequence.next( some_sequence )` will immediately find the `next` you defined and Lua won't bother to look at the metatable and so on.)